# trouble adding 2 or more images to the pane Javafx

Tags: java, javafx, pane, loadimage

I'm programming an easy version of BlackJack in javafx but I lost my road home I guess! I need to show cards in 2 rows when I click hit button.
How can I add different images in a row when I click a button? I tried to use `GridPane` and `BorderPane` but the images are shown at the same place... I know I need a for loop for each time I press the button but I'm not sure how to do it.. I made the same game in java swing and it went well

#### Desired layout

[image: I want something like this]

#### current layout

[image: but in javafx i cant get out of this]

here is my `loadImage` method

```
    public void ImageloadP(Card xPCard) {
        String xP = xPCard.toString();
        Image card = new Image("file:/Users/cetabije/Desktop/Apa/src/cards.png/" + xP + ".png");
        ImageView xPv = new ImageView(card);
        xPv.setFitHeight(140);
        xPv.setFitWidth(95);
        root.getChildren().add(xPv);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This **can** be done with a `GridPane`, but you have to specify the column/row index to prevent the `Node`s to be placed at the same position.

The following example uses `Rectangle`s for simplicity, but it works with any `Node` type:

```
private Color color = Color.BLACK;

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    GridPane gridPane = new GridPane(); 
    gridPane.setHgap(10);
    gridPane.setVgap(10);
    Button btn = new Button("Add Rect");

    // add node specifying column and row index
    gridPane.add(btn, 0, 0);

    gridPane.setStyle("-fx-background-color: lime;");

    btn.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
        color = color.brighter();
        Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(20, 20);
        rectangle.setFill(color);

        // append rect to second row
        gridPane.addRow(1, rectangle);
    });

    Scene scene = new Scene(gridPane, 500, 500);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

Note that if you use `gridPane.getChildren().add(node)` the default column/row index (`0`) is used, unless a different position is assigned in the properties of `node` using [`GridPane.setConstraints`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/GridPane.html#setConstraints-javafx.scene.Node-int-int-), [`GridPane.setRowIndex`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/GridPane.html#setRowIndex-javafx.scene.Node-java.lang.Integer-) or [`GridPane.setColumnIndex`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/GridPane.html#setColumnIndex-javafx.scene.Node-java.lang.Integer-)

Note that `BorderPane` is not the correct `Parent` to display multiple nodes next to each other unless they fit the "role" of top, left, center, right and/or bottom node (which isn't the case in your scenario).

Comment: Thanks it worked with boxes inside of a BorderPane (Y)

Answer (score 0):

Try using an HBox contained within your root node, that's initialized before you call your ImageLoadP method.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/HBox.html

http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Java/JavaFX/0300__JavaFX_HBox.htm

```
private HBox box;

public void initialize() { 
    box = new HBox();
    root.getChildren().add(box);
}

public void ImageloadP(Card xPCard) { 
    String xP = xPCard.toString();
    Image card = new Image("file:/Users/cetabije/Desktop/Apa/src/cards.png/" + xP + ".png");
    ImageView xPv = new ImageView(card);
    xPv.setFitHeight(140);
    xPv.setFitWidth(95);

    box.getChildren().add(xPv);
}
```